# Strip out all HTML Tags from an excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel file that has cells with text that includes HTML tags.

The data was exported from a database and the HTML tags were included.

The HTML is stored as text, but I need it gone.

Is there a quick easy way to remove it all (other than find/replace)?

Comment: This could probably be done with VBA, but it would be really helpful if you could post a few rows of the text so we could see a pattern and work the solution around it.

Comment: What is the matter with find/replace? Replacing "<*>" with "" is pretty effective.

Comment: @Mike Fitzpatrick - Can you use wild cards in find replace?  (If so that would work.)

Comment: Yes, you can use wildcards in Excel. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using Excel's search/replace with wildcards. You can use * to match any string (including empty string) or ? to match a single character.

So using:

`Find what: <*>`

`Replace with: leave blank`

will remove HTML tags from your cell contents.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did not know that Find Replace could support wild cards.

Comment: Didn't know you could use wildcard like this in F/R in Excel. Very useful!

Comment: To add to Mike's answer;Use the asterisk (**) to find any string of characters. For example, sm* finds "Smith" and "Smythe".
Use the question mark (?) to find any single character. For instance, gr?y finds "Gray" and "Grey".  Also, If you need to find actual asterisks or question marks in your Excel worksheet, type the tilde character (~) before them. For example, to find cells that contain asterisks, you would type ~* in the Find what box.  To find cells that contain question marks, use ~? as your search criteria.